# Running Riak as a non root user on RHEL

Tags: rhel, riak

I am new to Riak and just installed riak on a RHEL server.
Does anyone knows if it is possible to run riak without root or sudo permissions?

Can I just change some file/folder permissions to allow this?

Answer (score 1):

By default Riak creates a user and group riak:riak on installation.  If you run `riak start` as root, it will drop to the riak user before actually starting Riak.

You could use sudo or su to change to the riak user first, before calling the riak script.